# How can I insert a list returned from pyodbc mssql query into mysql through stored procedure using pymysql

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, pyodbc, pymysql

I am pulling data from a MSSQL db using pyodbc which returns my data set in a list. This data then needs to be transferred into a MySQL db. I have written the following stored procedure in MySQL.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `sp_int_pmt`(
    IN pmtamt DECIMAL(16,10),
        IN pmtdt DATETIME,
        IN propmtref VARCHAR(128),
        IN rtdinv_id INT(11)
    )
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO ay_financials.payment
    (
    pmtamt,
        pmtdt,
        propmtref,
        rtdinv_id
    )
VALUES
    (
    pmtamt,
        pmtdt,
        propmtref,
        rtdinv_id
    );

END
```

The procedure works fine if I am inserting one record at the time. So, for now, I am iterating over the list from my MSSQL query and call the procedure for each record. I am using this code:

```
cursor = cnxn.cursor()

cursor.execute("""  SELECT *
            FROM [%s].[dbo].[pmt]
            WHERE pmtdt BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-12-31'""" %(database))

a = cursor.fetchmany(25)

cnxn.close()

import pymysql

# MySQL configurations
un = 'ssssssss'
pw = '****************'
db = 'ay_fnls'
h = '100.100.100.100'

conn = pymysql.connect(host=h, user=un, password=pw, db=db, cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)

cur = conn.cursor()

for ay in a:
    cur.callproc('sp_int_pmt',(ay.pmtamt,ay.pmtdt,ay.propmtref,ay.rtdinv_id))

conn.commit()
```

The problem I will have in production is this list will contain 10,000-100,000 every day. Iterating over that data doesn't seem like an optimized way to handle this.

How can I use the full list from the MSSQL query, call the MySQL procedure one time and insert all the relevant data?

Comment: Do the MySQL server permissions require you to use that stored procedure to perform the inserts, or are you also able to INSERT rows directly into the table with the credentials you use to connect from your Python script?

Comment: there is no requirement that i have to use stored procedures, i am doing that to keep consistency with all of the other work required in this project..

Answer (score 1):

> How can I use the full list from the MSSQL query, call the MySQL procedure one time and insert all the relevant data?

You can't do that with your stored procedure as written. It will only insert one row at a time, so to insert *n* rows you would have to call it *n* times.

Also, as far as I know you can't modify the stored procedure to insert *n* rows without using a temporary table or some other workaround because MySQL does not support table-valued parameters to stored procedures.

You can, however, insert multiple rows at once if you use a regular INSERT statement and `.executemany`. pymysql will bundle the inserts into one or more multi-row inserts

```python
mssql_crsr = mssql_cnxn.cursor()
mssql_stmt = """\
SELECT 1 AS id, N'Alfa' AS txt
UNION ALL
SELECT 2 AS id, N'Bravo' AS txt
UNION ALL
SELECT 3 AS id, N'Charlie' AS txt
"""
mssql_crsr.execute(mssql_stmt)
mssql_rows = []
while True:
    row = mssql_crsr.fetchone()
    if row:
        mssql_rows.append(tuple(row))
    else:
        break

mysql_cnxn = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', port=3307,
                             user='root', password='_whatever_',
                             db='mydb', autocommit=True)
mysql_crsr = mysql_cnxn.cursor()
mysql_stmt = "INSERT INTO stuff (id, txt) VALUES (%s, %s)"
mysql_crsr.executemany(mysql_stmt, mssql_rows)
```

The above code produces the following in the MySQL general_log

```
190430 10:00:53     4 Connect   root@localhost on mydb
            4 Query INSERT INTO stuff (id, txt) VALUES (1, 'Alfa'),(2, 'Bravo'),(3, 'Charlie')
            4 Quit
```

Note that pymysql cannot bundle calls to a stored procedure in the same way, so if you were to use

```python
mysql_stmt = "CALL stuff_one(%s, %s)"
```

instead of a regular INSERT then the general_log would contain

```
190430  9:47:10     3 Connect   root@localhost on mydb
            3 Query CALL stuff_one(1, 'Alfa')
            3 Query CALL stuff_one(2, 'Bravo')
            3 Query CALL stuff_one(3, 'Charlie')
            3 Quit
```

Comment: gord - this makes sense, but let me ask one clarifying question. In your example, SELECT 1... UNION ALL, SELECT 2... UNION ALL. On days where I have 100,000 records that I need to move to MySQL, won't I wind up making 100,000 SELECT statement calls?

Comment: That was simply a way to create some test data without creating a table. Your code would just do a `SELECT ... FROM tablename` or similar.

Comment: ok that makes sense, just wasn't sure if there was a requirement for individual SELECT statements. I'll give this a try and let you know what happens.