# executemany: Failed executing the operation; Could not process parameters (Python)

Tags: python, mysql, sql, pyodbc

I've written a bit of python code that essentially will take data from one database (SQL Server 2008) and insert it into another (MySQL). I am fairly new to python so am struggling to find the errors in my code.

My code is:

```py
import mysql.connector
import pyodbc

def insert_VPS(SageResult):
    query = """
INSERT INTO SOPOrderReturn(SOPOrderReturnID,DocumentTypeID,DocumentNo,DocumentDate,CustomerID,CustomerTypeID,CurrencyID,SubtotalGoodsValue,TotalNetValue,TotalTaxValue,TotalGrossValue,SourceTypeID,SourceDocumentNo)
VALUES(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)"""
    try:
        mydbVPS = mysql.connector.connect(
          host="serveraddress",
          user="username",
          passwd="password;",
          database="databse"
        )

        VPScursor = mydbVPS.cursor()
        print(SageResult)
        VPScursor.executemany(query, SageResult)


        mydbVPS.commit()
    except Exception as e:
        print('InsertError:', e)

    finally:
        VPScursor.close()
        mydbVPS.close()

def main():
    selectQuery = """
SELECT TOP 1 [SOPOrderReturnID]
      ,[DocumentTypeID]
      ,[DocumentNo]
      ,[DocumentDate]
      ,[CustomerID]
      ,[CustomerTypeID]
      ,[CurrencyID]
      ,[SubtotalGoodsValue]
      ,[TotalNetValue]
      ,[TotalTaxValue]
      ,[TotalGrossValue]
      ,[SourceTypeID]
      ,[SourceDocumentNo]
  FROM [Live].[dbo].[SOPOrderReturn]
"""


    try:
        mydbSage = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                      'Server=CRMTEST;'
                      'Database=Live;'
                      'UID=sa;'
                      'PWD=password;')

        Sagecursor = mydbSage.cursor()

        Sagecursor.execute(selectQuery)
        SageResult = tuple(Sagecursor.fetchall())


        mydbSage.commit()
    except Exception as e:
        print('MainError:', e)

    finally:
        Sagecursor.close()
        mydbSage.close()

    insert_VPS(SageResult)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The error I get:

```
D:\xampp\htdocs\stripe\group\beta>sql-sync.py
((10447177, 0, '0000091897', datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 18, 0, 0), 186150, 1, 1, Decimal('18896.95'), Decimal('18896.95'), Decimal('3779.39'), Decimal('22676.34
'), 0, ''),)
InsertError: Failed executing the operation; Could not process parameters
```

I have tested the select query (but not the INSERT one) and both connections in a more basic script and those all work fine. Can anyone see the issues?

Comment: MySQL uses backticks, not brackets, `[...]`, around identifiers like SQL Server.

Comment: I have updated the code above with those brackets taken out of the insert query (the other is run with SQL server). I am still getting the same error.

Comment: Might be an issue with data. Try printing *SageResult* before insert to see content.

Comment: I've added a print in and changed it so it only pulls one result in the select just to make it easier to look at. Can you spot any issues? (see updated output above)

Comment: I suspect that `SageResult` is a tuple of `pyodbc.Row` objects, and `mysql.connector` may not like those. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55924953/2144390) for a way to create a list of tuples instead.

Answer (score 0):

That should have been `except Exception as e` instead of `except Error as e:`

Comment: Thanks. That cleared up most of the errors. Now it is just saying "Error: Failed executing the operation; Could not process parameters". That is the exception in the Insert_VPS function.

Comment: I guess you shouldn't be using `[` and `]` in SQL queries.

Comment: The []'s are taken from a query generated in SQL server that works fine so I can't see that being the issue.

Comment: Are you sure that the `SageResult` is a tuple? You should check the type and its elements before performing `executemany()`.

Comment: I'm not sure. I'm pretty new to python so I don't really know what SageResult is being outputted as (I assumed a standard array).

Comment: Check this out. It might be helpful - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18244565/how-can-i-use-executemany-to-insert-into-mysql-a-list-of-dictionaries-in-python

Comment: The elements that you got from the `fetchall()` queryset also should be `tuples`. and try to print the values and type before `executemany()`.

Comment: I just checked and SageResult was a list, not a tuple so I added tuple() around the fetchall to convert it (I tested this separately and it works). However, I am still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Consider workarounds as the special datetime and decimal types may not translate effectively from pyodbc to mysql connector DB-APIs.

**CSV**

Use the popular form of data transfer using MySQL's fast [`LOAD DATA`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html) method.

```py
import csv
...

# SQL SERVER CSV EXPORT
mydbSage = pyodbc.connect('...')

Sagecursor = mydbSage.cursor()
Sagecursor.execute(selectQuery)
SageResult = Sagecursor.fetchall()

with open("/path/to/SageResult.csv", "w", newline='') as csv_file:
    cw = csv.writer(csv_file)
    cw.writerow([i[0] for i in Sagecursor.description])    # WRITE HEADERS
    cw.writerows(SageResult)                               # WRITE DATA ROWS  


# MYSQL CSV IMPORT
mydbVPS = mysql.connector.connect(...)

query = """LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/path/to/SageResult.csv'
           INTO TABLE SOPOrderReturn
           FIELDS TERMINATED BY
           ENCLOSED BY '"'
           LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
        """
VPScursor = mydbVPS.cursor()
VPScursor.execute(query)
```

---

**PyODBC**

Run both database connections with same API which requires downloading the [MySQL ODBC driver](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/) for your OS and replace the `mysql.connector`). This may resolve handling of those specific types.

```
# SQL SERVER SELECT QUERY
mydbSage = pyodbc.connect(driver="SQL Server", host="CRMTEST", database="LIVE",
                          uid="sa", pwd="password")

Sagecursor = mydbSage.cursor()
Sagecursor.execute(selectQuery)
SageResult = tuple(Sagecursor.fetchall())

# MYSQL APPEND QUERY
mydbVPS = pyodbc.connect(driver="ODBC Driver Name", host="hostname",
                         uid="username", pwd="password", database="database")

query = """INSERT INTO SOPOrderReturn (SOPOrderReturnID, DocumentTypeID, DocumentNo,
                                       DocumentDate, CustomerID, CustomerTypeID,
                                       CurrencyID, SubtotalGoodsValue, TotalNetValue,
                                       TotalTaxValue, TotalGrossValue, SourceTypeID,
                                       SourceDocumentNo) 
           VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, , ?, ?, ?)
        """

VPScursor = mydbVPS.cursor()
VPScursor.execute(query, SageResult)
```

---

**MS Access**

Use the Office app as a medium between both relational databases. Since you use SQL Server you may have Microsoft Office available with a possibility of its DBMS Office app: MS Access.

Technically, MS Access is like phpMyAdmin, a GUI console to a database (where app is often [conflated with its engine](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33216/ms-access-or-mdb-or-access-database-engine-or-ms-jet-ace)), except Access is not restricted to any one database but can supplement its default database, Jet/ACE SQL engine, with any known backend data and database source.

1. Create two [linked tables](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/import-or-link-to-data-in-another-access-database-095ab408-89c7-45b3-aac2-58036e45fcf6) (using ODBC connections) to the separate RDBMS's.
2. Create and then run `INSERT...SELECT` query on linked tables. This query will use Access' SQL dialect which supports `TOP` clause and bracketed names. Results should propagate immediately in MySQL table.

   ```sql
   INSERT INTO SOPOrderReturn_mysql_linked 
   SELECT TOP 50 [SOPOrderReturnID]
          ,[DocumentTypeID]
          ,[DocumentNo]
          ,[DocumentDate]
          ,[CustomerID]
          ,[CustomerTypeID]
          ,[CurrencyID]
          ,[SubtotalGoodsValue]
          ,[TotalNetValue]
          ,[TotalTaxValue]
          ,[TotalGrossValue]
          ,[SourceTypeID]
          ,[SourceDocumentNo]
   FROM SOPOrderReturn_mssql_linked
   ```
3. In fact, have Python run above query after linking tables in a saved database. Likely the MS Access ODBC driver may already be installed with the Office app or alternatively can be installed with [downloaded redistributable](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54920).

   ```
   # LIST OF INSTALLED DRIVERS
   print(pydbc.drivers())

   # MS ACCESS APPEND QUERY
   constr = r"DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ={'C:\\Path\\To\\Database\\File.accdb'};"

   accdb = pyodbc.connect(constr)
   cur = accdb.cursor()
   cur.execute('<APPEND QUERY USING LINKED TABLES>')
   ```